# JavaScript: Modify JSON entry in promise before final use

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

So I'm having some trouble. I have a map populated from a json file which works perfectly. However the client wants to truncate the description in the pin popup to 300 charters (rather than actually write text that fits). I thought I could change the description in the promise but it's not working, in fact it's having no effect at all. If anyone has an idea how to do this I'd really appreciate it.

```
fetch('/assets/map/markers.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response error.');
    })
    .then(charData => {
        let mapData = charData.map(item => item.description.split(0, 300).join(" "));
        createMap(mapData);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('There has been a problem: ', error.message);
    });
```

Comment: replace `item.description.split(0, 300).join(" ")` by `item.description.splice(0, 300)`

Comment: Have you tried what `'foobar'.split(0, 3)` does in isolation, and what `join`ing that back together results in…?

Comment: Are you sure you want `.split()` and not `.slice()`?

Comment: Also beside that issue ("split" vs "slice") your function is transforming the array of objects into just the description strings. Seems like what you should be doing is  using a `.forEach()` over the data to modify just the "description" fields of the items. However, it's hard to know exactly because you did not post an example of the data structure and it's not clear what `createMap()` does with its input.

Comment: AH, yes. It is slice...but that doesn't work either. It actually breaks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take some characters out from a string you can use [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

So change

`item.description.split(0, 300).join(" ")`

To

`item.description.substring(0, 300)`

Comment: Also be aware that `charData.map(item => item.description.substring(0, 300))` will return an array of strings, and not alter the `charData` object.